# Клонирование репозитория

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

Есть репозиторий. Командой `git clone` клонировал на другой компьютер. В репозитории есть ветки(пока они в ПР), которые пока не смержены в ветку мастер. Я могу как-то получить доступ к веткам в склонированном репозитории, которые пока в ПР?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

да, конечно. Нужно только знать имя (или угадать его, посмотрев на вывод `git branch -a`). Просто делаем

```
git checkout <имя ветки>
```

и готово.

Comment: что значит запись `remotes/origin/hm1_1` ?

Comment: она значит, что в удаленном репозитории (remotes) под псевдонимом (origin) (а это псевдомим по умолчанию для удаленного репозитория - как бы "оригинал") есть ветка hm1_1. Если нужно переключиться на нее, делайте просто `git checkout hm1_1`

Comment: вот мои ветки, а что эта [запись](http://take.ms/2aVNy) значит?

Comment: понял. Сейчас попробую

Comment: Командой `checkout` сразу создается новая ветка.

Comment: на рисунке написано, что текущая ветка мастер (там звездочка), вторая строка говорит, что при клонировании этого репозитория будет клонироваться именно мастер. А дальше просто список доступных удаленных веток.

Comment: Извините, все правильно получилось. Не внимательно посмотрел